# Magento 2 : Not able to place order. Error is following

Tags: magento2

> [2018-08-21 12:16:02] main.CRITICAL: Rolled back transaction has not
>   been completed correctly. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0):
>   Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly. at
>   /home/groceryp/www.tripochure.com/bikeon/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:270)"}
>   []

Answer (score 0):

We have been experiencing this issue across all of our Magento 2 sites. For us, switching off persistent cart `(Store > Configuration > Customer > Persistent Shopping Cart)` solved the issue. I really hope Magento can fix persistent cart, though, as we'd like to be able to use it again.

Comment: Unfonrtunately this did not help me as I don't have Persistent cart on.